# Falha na recuperação de fábrica de classes COM do componente CLSID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em meu pc que faz o seguinte: a partir de um upload de um documento word, ele gera um novo documento com algumas informações básicas. Pra gerar essas informações ele abre o documento modelo, localiza uma tag que há nesse modelo e substitui pelo conteúdo referente a cada tag (3 no total). No meu pc funcionou perfeitamente, contudo, quando passei para o servidor, ele fica com o seguinte erro da imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Detalhe**: abaixo de **Rastreamento de Pilha** existe uma linha que mostra o caminho do projeto do meu pc, mesmo a aplicação estando em outro computador.

Texto do erro:

> **Falha na recuperação de fábrica de classes COM do componente com CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} devido ao seguinte erro: 80070005 Acesso negado. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).**
>
> Falha na recuperação de fábrica de classes COM do componente com CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} devido ao seguinte erro: 80070005 Acesso negado. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
>
> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Falha na recuperação de fábrica de classes COM do componente com CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} devido ao seguinte erro: 80070005 Acesso negado. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
>
> O ASP.NET não está autorizado a acessar o recurso solicitado. Recomenda-se conceder à identidade de solicitação do ASP.NET direitos de acesso ao recurso. O ASP.NET tem uma identidade de processo-base (geralmente {MACHINE}\ASPNET no IIS 5 ou Serviço de Rede no IIS 6 e IIS 7, e a identidade de pool do aplicativo configurada no IIS 7.5) que é usada se o aplicativo não estiver sendo representado. Se o aplicativo estiver sendo representado através de , a identidade será o usuário anônimo (geralmente IUSR_MACHINENAME) ou o usuário de solicitação autenticado.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

Comment: Era após o upload. Resolvi esse problema colocando as devidas permissões em SERVIÇOS e Componentes. Deu muito trabalho, pois tinha outras permissões. Era a DLL do Word. @Randrade

Answer (score 7):

Erros semelhantes a este podem ocorrer devido aos seguintes fatores:

- A falta das DLLs não estarem registradas no servidor
- Não ter instalado o Office no servidor.
- O Office instalado é 32bit e o servidor 64bit

Todavia se tem certeza que está tudo correto, você deve ter deixado de configurar algo no servidor conforme estas respostas do *SOen*:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26295661/1518921
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833718/1518921

Conforme a resposta mais antiga, siga os seguintes passos:

- No cmd ou <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> digite:

  ```
  DCOMCNFG
  ```
- Se o seu servidor estiver em inglês:

  - Abra <kbd>Console Root</kbd> > <kbd>Component Service</kbd> > <kbd>Computers</kbd>
  - Clique com o botão direito do rato (mouse) <kbd>My Computer</kbd> e selecione <kbd>Properties</kbd>
  - Vá até a aba <kbd>COM Security</kbd> > <kbd>Launch and Activation Permissions</kbd> e clique em <kbd>Edit Default</kbd>
- Se o seu servidor estiver em português:

  - Abra <kbd>Raiz de controle</kbd> > <kbd>Serviços de componentes</kbd> > <kbd>Compuradores</kbd>
  - Clique com o botão direito do rato (mouse) <kbd>Meu computador</kbd> e selecione <kbd>Propriedades</kbd>
- Vá até a aba <kbd>Segurança COM</kbd> > <kbd>Permissões de inicialização e Ativação</kbd> e clique em <kbd>Editar Padrão...</kbd>
- Clique no botão <kbd>Adicionar</kbd> (<kbd>Add</kbd> se for inglês) e digite no campo de texto `IIS_IUSRS` por exemplo ou adicione um serviço, deve ficar algo como:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

  > 1. Nota: O [`IIS_IUSRS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc515176(v=cs.70).aspx) é um grupo de usuários do IIS
  > 2. Nota: No Windows server 2003 o grupo é [`IIS_WPG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544832(v=cs.70).aspx)
- Clique em Ok, mas não feche a próxima tela
- Nesta janela que sobrou marque as opções, como na imagem:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Depois basta clicar em Ok nas janelas seguintes e fechar o que for necessário, assim deverá funcionar.

> Estou editando a pergunta, pois estou testando ainda

---

Conforme a resposta mais recente:

Aparentemente conforme estes passos você irá liberar acesso apenas ao COM do especifico desejado, todavia tome cuidado, faça apenas o que é pedido aqui:

- No cmd ou <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> digite:

  ```
  DCOMCNFG
  ```
- Se o seu servidor estiver em inglês:

  - Abra <kbd>Console Root</kbd> > <kbd>Component Service</kbd> > <kbd>Computers</kbd> > <kbd>DCOM Config</kbd>
- Se o seu servidor estiver em português:

  - Abra <kbd>Raiz de controle</kbd> > <kbd>Serviços de componentes</kbd> > <kbd>Compuradores</kbd> > <kbd>Config DCOM</kbd>
- Procure pelo componente por exemplo `Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document` e clique com o direito do rato (mouse) e vá em propriedades, por exemplo:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

  > Se o componente desejado não estiver listado é porque você está com a versão x86 do Office e o seu sistema operacional é 64bit, ou porque não tem o office instalado ou os componentes devidamente registrados
- Vá até a aba <kbd>Segurança</kbd>
- Na áreas <kbd>Permissões de inicialização e Ativação</kbd> e <kbd>Permissão de acesso</kbd> adicione o usuário `IIS_IUSRS` e as permissões.
- Depois vá clicando em <kbd>Ok</kbd>