# No Visual Studio 2017 a opção Extensões e Atualizações... dentro de Ferramentas não abre e dá mensagem de erro

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Reinstalei o Visual Studio 2017 (tentei várias vezes até conseguir, tive que apagar algumas pastas que continham o nome Visual Studio para conseguir reinstalar, senão não prosseguia), após a reinstalação, quando vou em FERRAMENTAS e clico em EXTENSÕES E ATUALIZAÇÕES, dá o seguinte erro:

[image: Imagem do erro]

O que fazer para resolver isso?

Comment: Acredito que a resposta esteja aqui. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54278/falha-na-recupera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-f%C3%A1brica-de-classes-com-do-componente-clsid